# Cordova Xcode 8 Archive Signing Conflict

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, compilation

I have been building IOS Apps using Cordova and Xcode (8.2.1 at present). When I go to Archive in Xcode, I get an error something like "Code signing conflict between automatic and manual". I haven't seen a solution anywhere else but stumbled on a fix which I have recorded below for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode go to the General tab in main screen, go down to the Signing section.

Turn off "Automatically manage Signing". Now turn it back on, you should see a message warning that other signing settings will be reset.

Now go to Xcode menu bar and choose Product/Archive and hopefully get the "Build Succeeded" message.